# visual selection in bash / cli

Tags: bash, vim, vi, command-line-interface

Is there a way to make **bash** use **visual selections** for **text replacement**?

Standard text input conventions don't work:

1. If you press Shift+Left Arrow, the character to the left should be visually selected
2. If you press Ctrl+Left Arrow, the cursor should move to the beginning of the previous word
3. If you press Shift+Ctrl+Left Arrow, the word to the left should be visually selected
4. If you visually select some text then press any key, the text should be replaced with the text of the key you press

Vi mode (set -o vi) visual selection conventions don't work:

1. If you enter normal mode, press 'v' to enter visual selection, then press 'h', it should visually select the character to the left
2. If you enter normal mode, press 'v' to enter visual selection, then press 'B', it should visually select the word to the left
3. If you visually select some text and then press 'R', it should erase the text and leave you typing the replacement

Comment: Mouse selection is handled by your terminal emulator (or by gpm in linux terminal), not by your shell. Actually, I have not seen any shells that are able to use mouse events. You can probably write a script that will handle `<C-S-Left>` keypresses and emulate visual mode (zsh zle definitely allows that, but I am not sure whether you can highlight selection here; and it is useless without highligting), but it has nothing to do with the mouse.

Comment: When you talk about vi conventions, are you running with `set -o vi`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this [guy](http://identi.ca/raybuntu) did it for zsh:

> I've made a VI VISUAL Mode for !ZSH. Emulates !VIM 's visual mode "v" in the cmd-line. [http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~raybuntu/%2Bjunk/ZSH_stuff/annotate/head%3A/zle_vi_visual.zsh](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eraybuntu/%2Bjunk/ZSH_stuff/annotate/head%3A/zle_vi_visual.zsh)

it's awesome!

Comment: how do i use this? ..install by adding `source <file>` in ~/.zshrc?.. the original code is from: http://stchaz.free.fr/mouse.zsh and is discussed at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444601/any-terminal-shell-with-mouse-support  ..doesnt do ctrl+shift+left (or right) selection, but might be able to be used for that.. for me this key combo isnt recognized (which would be required for mapping) following this: https://superuser.com/a/1120969 to use `cat` and then the key combo.. however alt+left/right might work to map ^[[1;3D and ^[[1;3C, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to do this in ZSH I use `edit-command-line`. You can add the following into your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Then I can just type `v` in command mode and it will open up my `$EDITOR`. You can do the same thing in Bash by just typing `v` in command mode without any customization.

Comment: It is true that you can type "v" to open up full vim, which enables visual selections just fine, but then you loose bash's contextual autocomplete, which is essential. I wonder if there's a way to configure it so that vim uses it's auto complete commands C-x C-p C-n etc to use bash complete ...

Comment: That would be an awesome plugin! I did a quick search but didn't find anything.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to my question, but you should get credit for trying. I actually don't think there is a program that obeys conventions written for the terminal - astounding. Sounds like a GSOC project to me ...