# zsh command line editor: go back to previous lines when entering a command

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

**Note that I'm NOT talking about previous lines in the history. I'm talking about previous lines in the current multiline command.**

When I type a multiline command in zsh, for instance (`_` indicates the cursor):

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do
for> echo i_
```

At this point I might change my mind and want to let `i` loop through `{1..10}` instead, so I need to go back to the previous line. However, I can't figure out how to do this, as ⌫, or ←, or `C-b`, or whatever I can think of all stops at the beginning of the second line. So, is it possible at all to move back? Thanks in advance.

In fact, this is not limited to zsh. For instance, I've never figured this out in bash either.

I've already spent a fair amount of time Googling without any findings, so please excuse me and blame my Google-fu if this is obvious.

---

For your reference, I'm using Emacs keybinding, and

```
$ bindkey | grep delete
"^D" delete-char-or-list
"^H" backward-delete-char
"^[[3~" delete-char
"^?" backward-delete-char
```

Not sure whether this will help.

Comment: I do not think this is possible in `bash` at least, but not sure about `zsh`. The problem is that once you have hit `Enter` after typing the first line, `bash` will remember that line but no longer accepts input from that line.

Comment: If you want to edit multi-line commands frequently without putting them into a shell script, at least in `bash`, if you are in `vi` mode, you can type `v` to open the editor whose path is stored in `$VISUAL`. I am not sure of the equivalent for emacs key bindings.

Comment: @merlin2011 Thanks for the info. I'm not very familiar with `vi` though, could you please explain "type `v` to open the editor..."? I mean, what exactly do I type to open the editor (certainly not a single `v`, is it)?

Comment: I'll write this as an answer, not because it addresses your question, but because I need multiline.

Comment: For those who vote close: this question *is* about programming, at least tangentially. Plus, there are a ton of command line editing questions on SO; better close them first if you insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible, but here are other workarounds:

1. You can just write everything in one line. It is not easy to edit, but multiline strings are not easily editable either.
2. You can bind some key (e.g. `<C-Enter>` if you can tell your terminal not to output `<C-m>` in this case) to

   ```
   function _-add-newline()
   {
       LBUFFER="$LBUFFER"$'\n'
   }
   zle -N add-newline _-add-newline
   bindkey "\Ca" add-newline
   ```

   . This way if you press `<C-a>` newline will appear in the buffer, but it will not trigger accept-line widget and previous line will still be editable. You can e.g. use left/right arrows to move to it.
3. If you type `for x in y ; do<CR>echo foo<CR><C-c><Up>` you will see `for x in y ; do\necho foo` in your buffer and all text will be editable. Note: you need `<CR>` to preserve last line (line aborted by `<C-c>` is not saved) and `<C-c>` to abort input; this variant will not work if you have already typed `done` (first `<CR>` will run the cycle). In last case you may discard last line with `<C-c>` and retype it.
4. Theoretically you may override `accept-line` widget with a code that parses your input and determines whether you have written command completely and if not then it will just append `\n` to the buffer (like in the above function) and do not run original `accept-line`, otherwise original `accept-line` is run. This variant is much harder to implement though, so I am saying “theoretically”.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your answer is good enough for this question, and I'm accepting it. However, you know what, the question is actually kind of deceptive. Secretly the most important reason I need to go back is that sometimes I screw up by accidentally hitting the enter prematurely ;) So solution (1) is ruled out. Solution (3) is what I've been doing, which leads to a ugly command line and dirty history. (2) is very interesting (I'd point out `C-a` is already bound), but still does not prevent accidents from happening. I guess the overall answer is "no"... I'm stuck with (3).

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you would `visual` mode in `bash`'s `vim` mode.

Inside `.bashrc` put the following lines.

```
set -o vi

# I do not remember which one of these is used by `v`, so I set both
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/nano
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
```

Reload `bash`, and then push `Esc` to go into `normal` mode. 
Type `v`, and `nano` should load. You can now enter your multiline command into `nano`. When you save and exit, the multiline command will be executed.

---

For `zsh`, the following lines in your `rc` may do it. I stole the last three lines from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899111/391161) and tested it on my `zsh`.

```
bindkey -v
autoload -U edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Comment: This is actually not a bad answer at all. It solves a possible XY problem.

Comment: @Qix, The problem is that he is asking about `zsh` and this describes a solution with `bash`. I guess the OP will tell us whether it helps his situation. :)

Comment: Can you find a similar solution in `zsh`? I've yet to come across something `bash` can do that `zsh` can't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It indeed works. I'll continue to hunt for an Emacs solution though (unfortunately Emacs is my favorite). By the way, there's a typo in the bash code: should be `export VISUAL` rather than `export $VISUAL`.

Comment: @Qix Do you know a zsh way to `export -f`? That's the first barrier I encountered after switching to zsh, and I haven't found a solution to this day. That's why I write bash scripts instead zsh scripts when I need something like GNU Parallel.

Comment: @KevinSayHi How I see it `export -f` is an ugly hack which does two things: 1. adds another attack vector (you can export a function named `echo` or `cat`!) and 2. makes it impossible to obtain values of specific environment variables directly (see output of `env` after `export -f` and try to obtain new variable with usual `$var` syntax). I think you may use `command_not_found_handler` in zsh to emulate `export -f` behavior (search for this name in `man zshmisc`) if you want, but for me `export -f` sounds like yet another argument against using bash.

Comment: @ZyX To me it's an ugly and somewhat strange but sometimes rather useful hack. I'll try to figure out the `command_not_found_handler` thing.

Comment: @KevinSayHi By the way, why do you need `export -f` for this? I just used usual subshells: e.g. [my implementation of job pool](https://sourceforge.net/p/vimpluginloader/dev-tools/ci/3e1f47879483fab32afe834cc7942b9c83ec14dc/tree/parjobs.zsh). Usage is as easy as prepending `addjob` to the command and adding `waitjobs` where you need to wait for all jobs to finish (and `kill -USR1` this script to print running jobs). This implementation was only intended to be used from scripts (specifically in testing framework), do not try it in interactive shell.

Comment: @ZyX Sorry, I didn't quite get it: why do I need `export -f` for what? I mean, I use `export -f` for [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which is a nifty perl script that does much more than parallelizing. I use it all the place as a super powerful version of `xargs`.

Comment: @KevinSayHi Parallel looks good, but it lacks some flexibility even on the tasks I use parallel execution for. I do not need some advanced features like distributed execution, but I want to configure reaction on signals and its output (--bar). By the way, I have not mentioned how to get function body in zsh: use `whence -f`, you can just literally pass it to `zsh -c`.

Comment: @ZyX Yeah, although I don't typically make use of signals, I also find some other limitations in my usage cases. But the point is it's just way better than xargs. And it's actively developed, so you can suggest features if you'd like to. `whence` looks nice (looks like it came from `ksh`? Never heard of it in bash...), I'll look into it.

Comment: @KevinSayHi AFAIR zsh developers know features of all other used shells out there. `whence` is a command that is used almost for everything `which`-related: `which` is officially an “alias” to `whence -c`, so is `type` and `where` (though with different arguments instead of `-c`). If you do not like name `whence` you can replace `whence -f` with `type -f` (`which` and `where` do not work even though `whence -cf` and `whence -caf` do work: most likely they were limited to emulate only features of other implementations, one cannot thus add `-f` just in case other implementation will).

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is possible.

While on that second line, pres `Esc + X` in order to execute a command,
and type `push-line-or-edit` (note that you can use Tab key for completion)
, then press `return`.

The prompt will change to a traditional one ditching your `for>` part from
continuation line, and you will have a new buffer filled with all your
previously typed lines, which of course now you can easily edit using well
known `C-a` or `C-b` keys.

Comment: Yes. And `push-line-or-edit` is usually bound to `C-q` and `M-q` (I believe), or one can set a custom keybinding using `bindkey`. (I was a total newbie to ZLE when I asked this question.)

Comment: @kYuZz This is a good answer, and as I pointed out in the comment above, I've figured it out by the time the answer was posted (but the "usually bound" part is technically incorrect; it's unbound by default, but Prezto binds it to `M-q`, shadowing `push-line`). However, I deem it rude to cancel an acceptance on an answer more than a year after it was awarded. If you like this answer, just award an upvote.